# Issue with Re Querying Underlying Data for ComboBox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm having an issue refreshing the query that underlies a combobox in a form named 'Site'. What I'm attempting to have happen is for a user to be able to enter a staff member in a form called 'Staff'and then on save have 'Staff' quit, the user be taken back to 'Site' and have the recently entered data be available in the combobox that will be informed by a query based partly upon the information received through 'Staff'.

Everything works so far except I have been unable to properly refresh 'Site' or the particular control being affected; Site.OfficeContactId. I'm using a macro but I converted to VBA for the posting.

```
    Function Macro2()
On Error GoTo Macro2_Err

    With CodeContextObject
        On Error Resume Next
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
        If (.MacroError <> 0) Then
            Beep
            MsgBox .MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
        End If
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "Staff"
        DoCmd.Requery "Forms!Site.Controls!OfficeContactId"
    End With


Macro2_Exit:
    Exit Function

Macro2_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Macro2_Exit

End Function
```

As I understand `Do.CmdRequery "Forms!Site.Controls!OfficeContactId"` should do the trick but it's not working for me.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: No error message, it just does not work. Pressing F5 when in Site resets the form such that the combobox is refreshed but the 'docmd.requery' will not function in the same way.

Comment: Wasn't really an approach as much as it was what converted with the macro, if I were to remove that element of the code would that likely push me in the right direction in identifying the error?

Comment: Made the button respond only to the following `Private Sub Form_Click()

        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "Staff"
        DoCmd.Requery "Forms!Site.Controls!OfficeContactId"
End Sub` and now nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Removed ancillary code that inhibited debugging. Truncated to 3 commands

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSave Record
DoCmd.Close acForm "Staff"
DoCmd.Requery "Forms!Site.Controls!OfficeContactId"
```

Now working to resolve a known issue where the requery command won't run in a non visible form, debugging code to call the form forward prior to the execution of requery.